# Show that the sequence $a_n = \frac{2^n+\cos{(n\pi)}3^n}{5^n}$ converges to $0$.

Tags: calculus

Show that the sequence $a_n = \frac{2^n+\cos{(n\pi)}3^n}{5^n}$ converges to $0$.
Would we use the squeeze theorem in this case? Please help.

Comment: Did you try to use arithmetic of limits? Do you know that $a^n\to 0$ when $0<a<1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how would I prove it:
$$-1 \leq \cos (n \pi) \leq 1$$
When
$\cos(n \pi)=-1$,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2^n-3^n}{5^n}=0$$
as $2^n-3^n \leq 5^n$, when $n \geq -1$ and both $2^n-3^n$ amd $5^n$ are motonically increasing.

When
$\cos(n \pi)=1$,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2^n+3^n}{5^n}=0$$
as $2^n+3^n \leq 5^n$, when $n \geq 1$ and both $2^n+3^n$ amd $5^n$ are motonically increasing.

So,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2^n+ \cos(n \pi)3^n}{5^n}=0$$
This is in no way rigorous, just my thoughts.

Comment: Thank you very much looks good to me!

Answer (score 1):

Gift:

$$\cos(n\pi)=(-1)^n\quad\quad$$ then $$a_n=\left(\dfrac25\right)^n+\left(-\dfrac35\right)^n$$

Comment: u dont need gift, just $||\cos||_\infty \le 1$

Comment: @mathworker21 The point is that by doing this, the limit becomes more immediate without having to appeal to all the write-up that would be required of a Squeeze Theorem solution.

Comment: @mathematics2x2life i disagree

Comment: @mathworker21 Congratulations?

Comment: How would we do it using the squeeze theorem?